# PHP version error

Tags: php, symfony, osx-mavericks

On my 10.9 Mac i installed Symfony via

`"sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony"`

and

```
"sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony"
```

When I did

```
"symfony new my_project_name"
```

it said:

```
"[RuntimeException]                                                    
  The selected version (3.2.1) cannot be installed because it requires  
  PHP 5.5.9 or higher and your system has PHP 5.4.45 installed."
```

Then I upgraded PHP with:

`"curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6"`.

The phpinfo showed me 5.6.27.
But the symfony new project error keeps on staying...

Comment: Check if the PHP used by the CommandLineInterface (CLI) is the same as the one used by the webserver. You might have updated only one of them.

Comment: That´s odd: CLI says 5.4.45 and the running apache / phpinfo in the browser says 5.6.27. So how could i fix this?

Comment: "which php" will tell you where is located the php binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> CLI says 5.4.45 and the running apache / phpinfo in the browser says
>   5.6.27

Your CLI PHP version is outdated, while the one used by Apache is up to date.

To use the same version for them, check first where the CLI version is located by taping

```
which php
```

It should return something like `/usr/bin/php`.

Rename this old version:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5445
```

Then create a symbolic link to the right version:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remember that the version of the CLI and the webserver are different.
It is a traditional problem.